# How to place the text inside donut chart (echarts)

Tags: echarts

I'm new one of echarts, I need to set the text in centre of donuts chart. I tried and google it no use, I tried it by html also but I cant able to achieve it. Please any one suggest me, How can I resolved it. Thanks in advance.

In options I add the total in title but I need to show that one into centre.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('pieChart1'));

var idx = 1;
pieChartOption =  {
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        formatter: '{a} <br/>{b}: {c} ({d}%)'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Total "+10+"%",
        left: 'center'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Test one',
            type: 'pie',
            radius: ['50%', '70%'],
            avoidLabelOverlap: true,
            label: {
                show: true,
                color: '#000',
                fontSize: '80',
                position: 'center'
            },
            emphasis: {
                label: {
                    show: true,
                    fontSize: '30',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            labelLine: {
                show: false
            },
            data: [
                {value: 10, name: 'Success', itemStyle : {normal : {label : { show : false},labelLine : { show : false}, color: '#5E50A1'}}},
                {value: 20, name:'Failed', itemStyle : {normal : {label : { show : false},labelLine : { show : false}, color: '#FFB200'}}},
                {value: 30,name:'Onprocess', itemStyle : {normal : {label : { show : false},labelLine : { show : false}, color: '#FF434F'}}}
            ]
        }
    ]
} 
myChart.setOption(pieChartOption);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Using ECharts</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- 为ECharts准备一个具备大小的Dom-->
  <div id="pieChart1" style="height:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;"></div>
  
</body>
  <!--引入echarts. Using echarts-all.js for convenience -->
  <!-- CDN is taken from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/echarts -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/2.2.7/echarts-all.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you do not plan to place labels in the center, only the total, right? In this case the most simple option it is a markPoint (see [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/wbgfzyk0/2/)):

```js
series: [{

  // ...

  markPoint: {
    tooltip: { show: false },
    label: {
      show: true,
      formatter: '{b}',
      color: 'black',
      fontSize: 20,
    },
    data: [{
      name: 'Total 10%',
      value: '-',
      symbol: 'circle',
      itemStyle: { color: 'transparent' },
      x: '50%',
      y: '50%',
    }],
  },

  // ...

}]
```

[image]

P.S. Library that you included in example is very strange (copyrights?, binary data?) and distort default behaviour. Please don't use them, take the any pack from the repo instead https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/echarts?path=dist

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `graphic` property, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/motz75an/

```
  graphic: {
    elements: [{
      type: 'text',
      left: 'center',
      top: 'middle',
      z: 999,
      style: {
        text: `Total 10%`,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 26,
      }
    }]
  },
```